# How do you derive the time complexity of alpha-beta pruning?

Tags: time-complexity, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I understand the basics of minimax and alpha-beta pruning. In all the literature, they talk about the time complexity for the best case is O(b^(d/2)) where b = branching factor and d = depth of the tree, and the base case is when all the preferred nodes are expanded first.

In my example of the "best case", I have a binary tree of 4 levels, so out of the 16 terminal nodes, I need to expand at most 7 nodes. How does this relate to O(b^(d/2))?

I don't understand how they come to O(b^(d/2)).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O(b^(d/2)) correspond to the best case time complexity of alpha-beta pruning. [Explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning):

> With an (average or constant) branching factor of b, and a search
>   depth of d plies, the maximum number of leaf node positions evaluated
>   (when the move ordering is pessimal) is O(b*b*...*b) = O(b^d) – the
>   same as a simple minimax search. If the move ordering for the search
>   is optimal (meaning the best moves are always searched first), the
>   number of leaf node positions evaluated is about O(b*1*b*1*...*b) for
>   odd depth and O(b*1*b*1*...*1) for even depth, or O(b^(d/2)).  In the
>   latter case, where the ply of a search is even, the effective
>   branching factor is reduced to its square root, or, equivalently, the
>   search can go twice as deep with the same amount of computation.
>
> The explanation of b*1*b*1*... is that all the first player's moves
>   must be studied to find the best one, but for each, only the best
>   second player's move is needed to refute all but the first (and best)
>   first player move – alpha–beta ensures no other second player moves
>   need be considered.

Put simply, you "skip" every two level:

[image]

O describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity, so in your case comparing precisely O(b^(d/2)) with small values of b and d doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I have found this more formal proof on the internet, it seems reasonable : http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~bylander/cs5233/a-b-analysis.pdf